Is it possible to delete an android developer account if we don't verify account with ID?
I recently learnt that it is impossible to delete a google play developer account if there are applications published whatever it is with previous (former in the past) or actives installs recorded by google play... like google said here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en#zippy=%2Cif-you-have-published-an-app except if we transfer apps to another developer account...

If you've published an app using your developer account and want to delete your account, you'll need to:
Sign in to your original account to backup or download your information before requesting an account deletion. If you delete a Play Console account, you won't be able to use it anymore.
Contact our support team to transfer your apps to another account.
Reply to the app transfer confirmation to close your existing account.
Note:
If you want to use the same developer name on a new account, you'll need to change your developer name on your existing account to a different name. Developer names can't be identical.
Deleting a Google Account will not automatically delete your developer account.

But I don't understand so why google indicate this to me, it's mandatory to verify account with ID (passport or other official ID document...) to keep my developer account and otherwise it will be deleted...

All developers must complete account verification to comply with the updated Play Console Requirements policy. If you do not complete account verification by October 31, 2024, your developer profile and apps will be removed from Google Play.

So, for me, avoiding to verify account ID verification is a way to delete a developer play store account... and all my apps without transferring them to another dev account ?

For one thing this is off topic for stack overflow as its not about programming. However I will say I did exactly what you are saying, I did not verify my account so that it would be deleted/deactivated

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/115145

@tyczj so tour account got deleted ?

@CommonsWare in which website it could be nice to post it in a stackexchange website

@user103031 it says the developer profile and apps have been deleted
